# Line number not showing when logging exception in IIS hosted service

Tags: wcf, exception, azure, logging, enterprise-library

I have a WCF service hosted On Azure.

I'm Logging exceptions using enterprise library in a flat text file.

The problem is that it is not logging line numbers in exception.

But when I run same service on local host it generate logs with proper stack trace and line number.

Comment: Looks like the pdb file is missing.

Comment: what is pdb file and how to add?

Comment: I have added all pdb files from my bin folder to server but still it is now adding line number :(

Comment: I have added these files using webmatrix in my azure server, is it ok? Or i should do something to send these files on azure while publishing

Answer (score 0):

In the publish Wizard go to settings and check the configuration drop down, if it is release set it to debug.